# NodeJS + Forever + Docker configuration doesn't work

Tags: node.js, docker, forever

I have a following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM    debian:stable

RUN      apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN      apt-get install -y curl
RUN      curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN      apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN      npm install forever -g

# App
ADD . /api
# Install app dependencies
RUN cd /api; npm install

EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["forever", "start", "/api/index.js", "8080"]
```

When I try to run `docker run -p 8080:8080 my-app@1.0.0` I get the following message:

> warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
>
> warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
>
> info:    Forever processing file: /api/index.js

and docker container stops.

What do I need to do to container work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Docker exits as soon as the given command is finished. `forever start SCRIPT` is starting the script as a daemon in the background, and then exiting. That's why your container stops.

To make it work, you should start `forever` in the foreground by using `forever SCRIPT`. The `CMD` in your `Dockerfile` should be:

```
CMD ["forever", "/api/index.js", "8080"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation